# KendoUI: kendo.ui.VirtualList is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm trying to implement `Virtualization` within `KendoUI`'s Combobox like so:

```
$('#my_select').kendoComboBox({
                autoWidth: true,
                filter: "contains",
                suggest: false,
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                virtual: {
                    itemHeight: 26,
                    valueMapper: (options) => {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Orders/ValueMapper",
                            type: "GET",
                            dataType: "jsonp",
                            data: convertValues(options.value),
                            success: function (data) {
                                options.success(data);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                },
                dataSource: {
                    type: "odata",
                    serverPaging: true,
                    pageSize: 10,
                    serverFiltering: true,
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url: 'path/to/url'
                        }
                    }
                },

            });
```

As mentioned in the documentation: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/virtualization
but I get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: kendo.ui.VirtualList is not a constructor
```

which is inside the core file of `KendoUI`!!
How to solve this problem ?

Comment: It is not quite clear how to replicate the issue - Kendo demo is working correctly. Would you please elaborate what is different at your side and possible provide a working [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely caused by the fact that you are using customized Kendo bundle and that bundle does not include ComboBox virtualization.

Please make sure that you did select "VirtualList" for "ComboBox".

[See example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uB7eV.png)